# How can I prevent my HTC Desire from overheating?

Tags: htc-desire, overheating

Recently I bought an HTC Desire overall I'm very happy with it. There seems to be one major flaw, it overheats quite easily causing it to reboot. I've run into this several times while driving using the navigation whilst recharging. Does anyone have any suggestions to workaround this problem? I've searched around but haven't found any helpful information.

Comment: Using while charging is generally a bad idea.  It'll be easier on your battery if it's off while charging, as well.  I understand it's necessary sometimes though.

Comment: I also purchased HTC Desire recently and I found it was overheating while using Internet on 3G networks. When using Wi-Fi it doesn't heat-up much. Additionally it has some battery issues. Battery is getting low too quickly and charging takes so long. However we shouldn't forget it has won Phone of the year award in many contests. So I'll continue with it. Lets see what it will do in future.

Answer (score 2):

[I also have a HTC Desire]

Your device overheats because its hardware is strained a lot during heavy use such as turn-by-turn navigation. This is compounded by the fact you probably have plugged it in the car charger as well, which is also known to generate some amount of heat (you probably have noticed this yourself when charging your phone normally).

There doesn't seem much that you can do to alleviate the problem, except turning off turn-by-turn navigation and only use the map to show you the route. You might also want to check whether there are other apps and services that strain unnecessary the device (frequent syncing could be an issue, as well as Bluetooth and mobile internet).

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem i bought my HTC desire 3 weeks ago and if i stay on the internet for around 5 minutes, the phone starts to become extremely hot and if i continue ton use it it will cut of and reboot. my solution was take of the back cover and expose the battery. Taking this measure it kept my phone a little cooler and did not have to reboot.

Comment: This is a Q&A site not a forum,it is expected from you to give technical answers. Although you can mention your personal experience but it should come with technical reasoning, not just an opinion. Back your claim with credible sources. See How to [Answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have a rooted HTC Desire. My phone used to overheat and reboot.

I tried to solve it by moving some of my apps from Phone to SD. The phone is generally good but the battery runs out very quick. I advise nobody to get a task killer application from the market as i have experienced that it kills the phone battery more.

I tend to use 3G mobile-internet and that made my phone to overheat and crash - after I started using WiFi, it made a difference. Also this phone has problems in general with the battery the best advice would be to get a new battery of Amazon or E-bay and it lasts twice as long and the phone doesn't overheat at all.

Answer (score -1):

Do not install unstable software. It is not stable. Then your mobile overheat.

Do not change CPU pulse rate. Keep normal number.

Keep free RAM and free space. Overload can heat mobile.

Some games need more RAM. It can overheat mobile.

Update operating system.

Comment: I disagree. Custom ROMs might not be as stable as some stock ROMs but only badly configured ROMs would overheat the device. By CPU pulse rate, do you mean frequency? If yes, what constitute as normal number? What does RAM has to do with overheating? Much of the heating that contributes to heating issues come from consistently high CPU and GPU cycles (too much electron flow, therefore, high generation of heat). If there is no stock update for ROM, what can a user do given that you asked them not to update to a custom ROM?

Comment: I said unstable custom ROM. You increase CPU pulse rate, it can heat mobile. You do not have memory and use high application, it can heat mobile.

Comment: You didn't say *unstable* [earlier](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/233487/1). // I can fill RAM to the brink of its limit, and it would still not contribute much in overheating.

Comment: I have written "it is not stable = unstable". Anyway you are senior I follow your instruction.