# My HTC Desire Keeps Overheating, what can I do to stop this?

Tags: htc-desire, overheating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent my HTC Desire from overheating?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/how-can-i-prevent-my-htc-desire-from-overheating)

I've just purchase a HTC Desire and after about 10mins of using it, it will overheat and crash onto the opening green HTC logo which you get when you turn the phone on. What can I do to prevent the phone from overheating?

Comment: How do you know it's overheating?  (And since you just purchased it, can you return it?)

Comment: Because the lower back of my phone gets really hot then crashes.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your best bet is to return the phone, since you have just bought it!

It is normal for all phones to heat up when using hardware resources like Camera or GPS, it is not normal to crash recurrently after a simple 10 minutes usage.

You can check some information about battery conditions using the dial code *#*#4636#*#*

One last thought: Does it happen all the time? I mean, sometimes it is hard to reproduce some kind of error or behaviour to the vendor because of its uncertainty and they might distrust you. But if you had just bought it, that should not be a problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the Desire is on T-Mobile, there was a [very long support thread](http://support.t-mobile.com/thread/3544?tstart=0) with folks reporting unusually high battery drain around the time this question was asked. The workaround seems to force usage 2G networks (EDGE or GPRS) as the problem seems to be with **all** phones on T-Mobile that talk 3G, not just Android phones.

(This doesn't affect me, as I'm on AT&T; I can't do better than 2G anyway. My T-Mobile prepaid backup phone has no data plan, so isn't affected either.)